# calculate the distance between the place where I am taking photo and the object I am taking

Tags: camera, exif, latitude-longitude

I can get the latitude and longitude where I am taking photo. I can also get the Exif information of the photo I took.

I want to know how can I calculate the distance between the place I am taking photo and the object I am taking by above informations?

give me some constructive opinions. thanks very much.

Comment: Err what reference point would you even use for that? You need some form of scale somewhere on the picture...

Comment: Why would you need the longitude and latitude?

Comment: If you took a picture of the same object from different latitudes and longitudes, you could use triangulation to find its position.

Answer (score 0):

You may get lucky with the [SubjectDistance](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/privateifd/exif/subjectdistance.html) exif tag. Note that not all cameras set this tag.